# undefined method `announce' for class `Class' (NameError) in rails error in octopus gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get the following error after I including the database sharding gem [octopus](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus) in my application ...can anybody help me in this?.....

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method': undefined method `announce' for class `Class' (NameError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb:31:in `alias_method_chain'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ar-octopus-0.3.4/lib/octopus/migration.rb:9:in `extended'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ar-octopus-0.3.4/lib/octopus/migration.rb:73:in `extend'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ar-octopus-0.3.4/lib/octopus/migration.rb:73
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ar-octopus-0.3.4/lib/octopus.rb:66
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
    from /var/www/scandetails/config/application.rb:7
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:38
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Comment: You need to provide code showing how you've included and called the gem.

Answer (score 7):

According to [this pull request](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus/pull/58), Rails 3.1 support has been added to the gem's master branch, but an updated version [has not be released](https://rubygems.org/gems/ar-octopus). You can use the master branch of the repository as the gem's source by referencing the github repository in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'ar-octopus', :git => "git://github.com/tchandy/octopus.git", :require => "octopus"
```

Answer (score 0):

I try use ar-octupos from master branch reporsitoty, but i'm still got error with bundle install.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
```

In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    activesupport (3.1.12)
  In Gemfile:
    ar-octopus (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0) ruby
Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.

Comment: and i try "bundle update" but still got - Bundle could not find compatible versions for gems "activesupport"